# Bind network link exclusively to Docker container

Tags: networking, docker, container

Is it possible, with Docker, to bind a host network link exclusively to a Docker container?

In other words, to move `eth1` (or whatever) into a container so that it is only avalilable to that container - neither the host nor any other containers/virtual machines, etc, running on the host should have access to it.

In Linux Containers (LXC) this is trivial, there is a `phys` network type that does exactly this:

> **phys:** an already existing interface specified by the `lxc.net.[i].link` is assigned to the container.

I am not [asking about routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26289351/bind-physical-nics-to-containers-for-docker) or using macvlan or [other hacks](https://serverfault.com/questions/688483/assign-physical-interface-to-docker-exclusively).

Ideally this will be possible using standard Docker commands, but from what I've read, I fear Docker's network implementation does not support this. A possible work-arounds using `ip` commands would be better than nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible with standard network commands. Features that would make this easy were explicitly rejected by Docker a few years back (https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/8216).

You can of course manually move an interface into the network namespace of a Docker container, but this is fraught with problems: for example, any time you restart or re-create the container, you'll have to re-configure your networking.

---

To add an interface to your container's network namespace:

1. Get the PID of your container:

   ```
   container_pid=$(docker inspect <container_name_or_id> -f '{{ .State.Pid }}')
   ```
2. Assign the interface to the container's namespace:

   ```
   ip link set netns ${container_pid} dev ${device}
   ```

And you're done...mostly.

If you want to configure the interface after adding it to the namespace, you'll have to either:

- Run your container with extra privileges. Probaly just `--cap-add=NET_ADMIN`, although you can also just use `--privileged` while you're testing things.
- Use `nsenter` to perform the configuration from outside of the container:

  ```
  nsenter -t ${container_pid} -n ip addr ...
  ```

---

While this all works, because of the limitations I've noted, I would just stick with the `macvtap` driver if I need a physical interface inside the container for some reason.  Or use `lxc` or `systemd-nspawn` or some other containerization tool that makes this particular task easier.